# Not able to retrieve Node List from Document when my XML tag contains "_" in it

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, w3c, xmlnodelist

I have a xml like this

```
<PARENT>
<TAG_1>
<ROLE>Architect </ROLE>
</TAG_1>
<TAG2>
<ROLE>Architect </ROLE>
</TAG2>
</PARENT>
```

I am using JAX-B framework for Marshalling and UnMarshalling.

The issue is while I am retrieving org.w3c.dom.NodeList, I am able to do for TAG2 which don't contain _ and unable to do for TAG1 which contains _(underscore)

`org.w3c.dom.NodeList nodeList = org.w3c.dom.Document.getElementsByTagName("TAG2")`  returns me length of 1 which is correct.

`org.w3c.dom.NodeList nodeList = org.w3c.dom.Document.getElementsByTagName("TAG_1")`  , it returns me length 0 but it should be 1  .

Can anyone suggest what can be the issue with the underscore and how to do with it because XML I can't change as given by the client.

Thanks

Comment: Can you check to see if org.w3c.dom.NodeList nodeList = org.w3c.dom.Document.getElementsByTagName("TAG1") works? JAX-B I guess by default tries to convert underscores to camel casing. Also, if you could post your un-marshalling code, I could help.

Comment: NodeList books = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("BOOKSAWARD") works but xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("BOOKS_AWARD")  not works if both BOOKSAWARD and BOOKS_AWARD are present in xml  For Unmarshelling I do Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = this.getJAXBContext().createUnmarshaller();  NodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("BOOKS_AWARD")     Node booksAwardNode = nodeList.item(0);Object obj = jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(booksAwardNode);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it works for me:

```
package com.stackof.helps.nonspring;

import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

/**
 * @author samuele m.
 *
 */
public class MixedTest
{
    @Test
    public void testPathItem() throws Exception {
        String xml = "<PARENT><TAG_1><ROLE>Architect </ROLE></TAG_1><TAG1><ROLE>Engineer </ROLE></TAG1></PARENT>";
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbFactory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
        dbFactory.setIgnoringComments(true);
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
        NodeList nodeList1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("TAG1");
        NodeList nodeList2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("TAG_1");
        Assert.assertEquals(1, nodeList1.getLength());
        Assert.assertEquals(1, nodeList2.getLength());

        NodeList engList = ((Element)nodeList1.item(0)).getElementsByTagName("ROLE");
        NodeList arcList = ((Element)nodeList2.item(0)).getElementsByTagName("ROLE");
        Assert.assertEquals(1, engList.getLength());
        Assert.assertEquals(1, arcList.getLength());

        String eng = engList.item(0).getTextContent().trim();
        String arc = arcList.item(0).getTextContent().trim();
        Assert.assertEquals("Architect", arc);
        Assert.assertEquals("Engineer", eng);
    }
}
```

Please check your code, since there is something wrong somewhere (file encoding?)

Comment: Ok , may be encoding issue but I tried html entities and all other possible combinations . still it not worked .   jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(BOOKSAWARD.class, BOOKSAWARDUNDERSCORE.class) and using code like above . Still I get Null pointer exception on exception nodelist.get(0) as nothing comes in nodelist for _ tag results     . Also I am using JAXB framework for marshalling and unmarshalling

Comment: can anyone help me on basis of above inputs ?

Comment: Step by step, please. We are just talking about nodelist, not unmarshalling: do you have a NullPointerException in unmarshalling (possible) or in doc.getElementsByTagName("TAG_1").item(0)? I changed code (and XML) using DOC1 and DOC_1 tags and it still works. So data you are reading doesn't have any DOC_1 tag.

Comment: Ok I have DOC1_tag in my XML data , I checked it again . Step 1 jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(BOOKSAWARD.class, BOOKSAWARDUNDERSCORE.class)    Document xmlDoc = getResponseFromWebservice()   Step2 NodeList books = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("BOOKS_AWARD")     here i get NPE as NodeList.length == 0  Step3

Answer (score 0):

My issue is resolved . Thanks a lot all for for your help and provide me insights . It was not an issue of underscore , but issue with hidden response filters in my code which i didn't knew and debugged to find out .

Comment: Nice to know :) Just in case, this snippet shows you what you really get in your Document (add it before step 2)
`DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(xmldoc);
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
transformer.transform(domSource, result);
System.out.println("XML IN String format is: \n" + writer.toString());`